# Confusion about file formats for Intel Fortran files

Tags: fortran, intel, gfortran

I am working on a project that was given to me by someone else. This project compiles using the `ifort` compiler and contains a ton of fortran .FOR files written in seemingly free- format. Recently I have been studying fortran code formats in a little more detail and came accross [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-effect-of-file-extensions-on-source-form) which states:

".f90 specifies Fortran free-form source and .f, .ftn, or **.for** specify fixed-form souce"

I don't understand why and how these .FOR files can compile OK if they are written in free form, and if ifort recognizes them as fixed form. Could anyone please fill me in on this? I'm trying to migrate this project to gfortran so I'm very confused. Also I do not want to change everything to .f90 files because I  am worried this might break something else.

Comment: Please show some example of the file which shows that it is free form. Look for line continuation.

Comment: It is proprietary software. I don't really feel comfortable showing it on here. Aside from posting the source code, how can I prove that it is in free-form?

Comment: You cannot. At least describe how it looks like, why you believe it is free form.

Comment: 1) Several of the lines go beyond column 72 (column 86 for example), 2) line continuations are done with ampersand (&) at the end of the line 3) Comments do not start in col.1 (for example col 59.)

Comment: Yes, that sounds like free form. Which compiler options are used to compile them with ifort?

Comment: difficult to tell. How can i find the makefile and/or compiler command in a Visual Studio 2010 project? One thing I did notice when the .FOR file is isolated from the solution and compiled with `ifort` in `cmd` it will not compile. However inside the solution it compiles.

Comment: I have no idea. But probably `-free` is being used. It may be a checkbox somewhere. The equivalent in gfortran is `-ffree-form` or similar, then you should be fine.

Comment: if you post that with like a specific command or something I can accept it as the final answer. Something like `gfortran ffree-form -c filename.for -o filename.o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free form source code can be stored and compiled in files with various extensions. If it is not the default extension, the compiler must be instructed to treat it as fixed form.

In Intel Fortran such flag is `-free` or the Windows equivalent `/Qfree`. In gfortran it is `-ffree-form`, so

```
gfortran -ffree-form source.for
```

compiles the `.for` file as free form.